# FOP-2.6 Custom Font are Not rendered in PDF

Tags: fonts, xsl-fo, apache-fop

After updating to FOP 2.6, while trying to use Apache FOP to use custom fonts GT Super Display Light, I am getting below error.

```
org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent
WARNING: Font "Symbol,normal,700" not found. Substituting with "Symbol,normal,400".
org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent
WARNING: Font "ZapfDingbats,normal,700" not found. Substituting with "ZapfDingbats,normal,400".
org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent
WARNING: Font "Arial,normal,700" not found. Substituting with "any,normal,700".
org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent
WARNING: Font "GTSuperDisplayLight,normal,700" not found. Substituting with "any,normal,700".
```

Configuration file:

```xml
<fonts>
   <!-- automatically detect operating system installed fonts -->
    <auto-detect/>  
    <!-- embedded fonts -->
    <!--
    This information must exactly match the font specified
    in the fo file. Otherwise it will use a default font.

    For example,
    <fo:inline font-family="Arial" font-weight="bold" font-style="normal">
        Arial-normal-normal font
    </fo:inline>
    for the font triplet specified by:
    <font-triplet name="Arial" style="normal" weight="bold"/>

    If you do not want to embed the font in the pdf document
    then do not include the "embed-url" attribute.
    The font will be needed where the document is viewed
    for it to be displayed properly.

    possible styles: normal | italic | oblique | backslant
    possible weights: normal | bold | 100 | 200 | 300 | 400
                      | 500 | 600 | 700 | 800 | 900
    (normal = 400, bold = 700)
    -->
    <font kerning="yes" embed-url="GTSuperDisplayLight.ttf" embedding-mode="subset">
        <font-triplet name="GTSuperDisplayLight" style="normal" weight="700" />
    </font>
</fonts>
```

Edit : adding Java File Which Calls Configuarion File and picks fonts installed on the user's computer, but custom fonts can be specified. Please refer to Apache FOP official

```
         /*
              * Register Apache FOP to use our fonts. By default we set this config file to auto-detect the fonts
         */
            File xconf = new File( getConfigFileURI( xslFullName ) );
            FopConfParser parser = new FopConfParser( xconf ); //parsing configuration
            FopFactoryBuilder builder = parser.getFopFactoryBuilder(); //building the factory with the user options
            fopFactory = builder.build();


            fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance( new File( "." ).toURI() );

            foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();
            bufferedOutputStream = new FileOutputStream( pdfFilename );
            bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream( 
            bufferedOutputStream );


           private String getConfigFileURI( String xslFilePath )
           {
               File f = new File( xslFilePath );
               String configFileURI = f.getParent() + "/userconfig.xml";

               return configFileURI;
           }
```

Comment: Are you telling FOP to use your configuration file (either in your java code or with `-c path/to/your.xconf` if you are calling it from the command line)?

Comment: @lfurini
 We are Calling it from our Java code

Comment: What makes you think GTSuperDisplayLight.ttf contains bold font? Just because you state the weight does not mean it will automagically be bold.

Comment: You need to match the real font (as in the TTF) with the weight and style. Like I cannot just say I have:

TimesNewRoman.ttf and then say have normal, bold, oblique and bold-oblique. That font is "normal" only, you need other font files that have bold, oblique and bold-oblique (meaning different TTF files)

Comment: @KevinBrown OP has explicitly registered the font with `weight="700"` in the configuration file, so that should not be _the_ problem; of course, registering a "normal" font with a bold weight will not make it bold, but the pdf should use it nonetheless.

Comment: Are there other warnings / errors besides the font-related ones? Could it be that FOP cannot find or open the configuration file?

Comment: @lfurini
 No there are no Error only above mentioned Wwarnings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Issue got resolved with JDK 11